# Lotus SameTime Chat History

Tags: history, chat, lotus-sametime

How do I get to yesterday's SameTime chat?

A guy sent me a URL yesterday via Lotus SameTime. I saved the chat.

Today, I opened Lotus SameTime. I clicked on File → Open Chat History and this is all I see:

[image]

So I click on each heading, and nothing happens. Nothing at all. I tried putting the guy's name in the "*search*" field near the top right. No result.

How do I get to this chat from yesterday?

Comment: How did you save the chat?

Comment: @SimonO'Doherty On the chat window I clicked on `File..Close`. Sametime asked me if I want to save the chat. I answered yes. Sametime placed a box on the screen for me. I accepted the default choices (path, filename, etc). That was the end of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you used the "Save Chat As...".

Open a chat window to the person again and do the "Save Chat As" again. It should give you a path where it saves the chat. Your earlier one should be there.

As for the UI above, I think that only works if you have Chat history enabled. Also you need to check your preferences to see if you have chat histories to auto-delete.

Comment: You got it Simon. I used that technique to find the path, and noticed that SameTime is placing the files there in *html* format. I then used my browser to open the files; climbing down the file path, and so on. Check and plus one for your answer. Thanks.